# Single word for "Not yet fixed" or "Not yet corrected"

Tags: single-word-requests

***Unremedied*** seems to be a single word in [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unremedied), but doesn't seem to be well recognized English word.

I'm looking to find a word that basically conveys, "***this infraction is not yet corrected***", where "*not yet corrected*" is the magic word you provide.

Comment: Context is everything in wrangling English idioms. Can you clarify? If it's a case of an infraction, "outstanding" could work. Other circumstances could be addresed by "pending," "unresolved" or "open."

Answer (score 3):

Unaddressed. Perhaps, unresolved.

Comment: These work.  Unaddressed would imply that no attempt had yet been made to correct the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Uncorrected** goes back at least 200 years, so it seems a pretty safe choice.

Comment: Does "uncorrected" imply the 'yet'? M-W defines uncorrected as "Not corrected". Is there a better word that conveys the "yet"?

Comment: @K- If it's uncorrected then it has not been corrected yet.